# Mock Axios multiple requests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, enzyme

So i bumped into this problem where i have 4 to 5 API calls sent in `componentDidMount` and i want to mock the response for some to test scenarios. This is how my `componentDidMount` look like

```
  this.updateTokenHOC(this.getCommentsData)
  this.updateTokenHOC(this.checkReviewer)
  this.updateTokenHOC(this.getStepDataFromServer,1)
  this.updateTokenHOC(this.getStepDataFromServer,2)
  this.updateTokenHOC(this.getStepDataFromServer,3)
  this.updateTokenHOC(this.getStepDataFromServer,4)
  this.updateTokenHOC(this.getStepDataFromServer,5)
```

Yup these all are API calls.
I have tried with [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) where i mock with `URL`,`Regex` requests.When i make axios call from testing environment it gives me mock response. but these calls change the state and that i dont find in my state.

The testing fail to mock this call. as you can see for debugging i made test property in state

```
  getCommentsData(config) {
const type = this.state.viewType
const id = this.state.requestId
instance.get(`/review/sections?request_id=${id}&request_type=${type}`, config)
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({test:'iam in comments data'})
    if (response.status === 200) {
      for (let step in response.data.sections) {
        if (response.data.sections[step].section_type === 'device_quota') {
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            steps: {
              ...this.state.steps,
              step1: {
                ...this.state.steps.step1,
                comments: response.data.sections[step].comments,
              },
            }
          })
        }
```

The alternative solution can be if i can test this method separately like in enzyme  wrapper.find('ViewReview').instance() but have not succeeded with that aswell.

P.S i have tried [Nock](https://github.com/nock/nock), [Jest-axios-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios) (this works but for multiple requests i cannot mock response for all),moxios

Comment: So state is not updated as you expect, is that the issue? How do you update the state, provide codebase

Comment: Actually i cannot mock the axios calls as mentioned above. since these call are made without any action (like button click, form submit etc).

Comment: Your http calls executed on mount, how do you mount the component in test?

Comment: const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />)

once mounted all the API calls will be executed. i have posted the answer how i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found the way to solve it.

using jest-axios-mock.

So what it does is stack your calls. If i have 4 calls in ComponentDidMount and i want to mock response of 2nd API call i will have to do like this

```
 let FirstAPIcallMockResponse = {
   data: {
    "SomeData": [
      {
        "SomeProperty": SomeValue,
        "SomeProperty": SomeValue,
      }
    ]
  },
  status: 200
}
let fakeResponse = {
   data: {},
   status: 404
}
mockAxios.mockResponse(fakeResponse)
mockAxios.mockResponse(responseObj)
mockAxios.mockResponse(fakeResponse)
mockAxios.mockResponse(fakeResponse)
```

NB: The fake response will status should be 404 or something otherwise in your API call body it will execute that section if you dont have condition if(response.status===200)